# Linking shared libraries to c++ project on the cluster

Tags: c++, static-libraries, cluster-computing, static-linking, tbb

I wrote the c++ project which uses tbb library. To link this library to my project I set in the project settings the paths to the library's files:

> Include directories: usr/tbb/include
>
> Libraries: usr/lib/libtbb.so, usr/lib/libtbbmalloc.so, usr/lib/libtbbmalloc_proxy.so

It worked on my PC, but when I tried to run it on cluster (via qsub), I've got error that the library path is not found. So my question is: **How can I specify the path to the shared library when I execute the program on cluster?**
I saw the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357869/error-while-loading-shared-libraries) and tried to run it this way

```
-L/home/dinar/tbb/lib/ia32 -Wl,-rpath,/home/dinar/tbb/lib/ia32 -ltbb ./program
```

but it did not work.

Comment: The `-L`, `-Wl` and `-l` flags are *linker* flags, i.e. flags you use when linking your program.

Comment: Thank you for response, Joachim. What I did is: I saved the tbb package in my user directory on the cluster and tried to link the libraries to my program. But it did not work for me. Probably my executable application still keeps the old library's path (the path on my PC) which I specified to build the project.

Answer (score 1):

The environment variable you might want to set is [`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html#AEN80).

Like

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/dinar/tbb/lib/ia32 ./program
```

Comment: I tried this too and I get error: ./program: error while loading shared libraries: libtbb.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: @DinarAbdullin And in `/home/dinar/tbb/lib/ia32` you have a file named `libtbb.so.2`? Of not do you have *any* file with a similar name (maybe more after the `.so.2`, only `.so` extension)? If the last, make a symbolic link from `libtbb.so.2.x` (or `libtbb.so`) to `libtbb.so.2`.

Comment: Joachim, in the /home/dinar/tbb/lib/ia32 I have libtbb.so and libtbb.so.2 files